# create classes at runtime from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

How can I create classes by using database entries in runtime?

for example:

**ID    (int) :**

### *1*

**Name  (string) :**

### *Product*

**Content (string) :**

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Family { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }      
}
```

or another pattern

its for dynamic page generator

---

**Update :**

more precisely i mean i need to have a class for each record of database not a class for each table , and this class most be able to give me ability to use usual instructions of SQL like CRUD

Comment: You should clarify your question , you want to make an offline code generator ? Or you want to populate some dynamic controls from DB ?

Comment: why you need to create a class? you can create a collection of fields instead. If you create a class dynamically, then you have to access its fields using some kind of reflection. That would produce a messy code. I suggest a Dictionary<string, object> instead.

Comment: Could it be that you are about to re-invent a Content Management System?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know about the data at compile-time, then there isn't much point building a class at runtime - you might as well use (gulp) `DataTable` (goes to wash hands). If you *do* know about the class at compile-time, then either **write the class** (as you have done) and use a tool like "dapper", or use an ORM tool such as EF, NHibernate, LINQ-to-SQL etc which will generate the types for you from the database (at design-time), and allow your code to interact with the type.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to create a class against database entries ? I suppose you want to create object against each entry for a class say Person. Its better that you create classes against each table and then create object against those class for records in database.  I think you are looking for ORM , check [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx). Also you can [create code at runtime](http://olondono.blogspot.com/2008/02/creating-code-at-runtime.html) using reflection, but I really don't see the need for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really create classes dynamically (well, you can, but it's a huge anti-pattern and not something I would recommend). The way I see it, you have 2 options:

1) Using the .Net 4 dynamic keyword.

2) Create a "generic" class that contains properties holding the type, an identifier and serialized data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JJMasterData](https://github.com/JJConsulting/JJMasterData), a library to generate CRUDs at runtime. On pull request [#13](https://github.com/JJConsulting/JJMasterData/pull/13), we developed C# class generation from database tables.
We support both .NET 6 and .NET Framework and many features out of the box, like data importation and exportation.